# Filter Folium MarkerCluster by Column from Dataframe

Tags: mapping, folium

I want to map a MarkerCluster with a filter by a column (QuadClass). I followed this answer: [Filter Folium Map based on marker color](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64435653/filter-folium-map-based-on-marker-color)
And it works for single markers, but when I try to use MarkerCluster nothing gets added to the map. is there anyway to achieve this?

```
Qclass = {1: "Verbal Cooperation",
      2: "Material Cooperation",
      3: "Verbal Conflict",
      4: "Material Conflict"}

m = folium.Map(location=[33.8564, 66.0867],
           tiles='Stamen Toner',
           zoom_start=6)

marker_cluster = MarkerCluster().add_to(m)
features = {}
for row in pd.unique(df1["QuadClass"]):
    features[row] = folium.FeatureGroup(name=row)

for index, row in df1.iterrows():
marker = folium.Marker([row['ActionGeo_Lat'], row['ActionGeo_Long']],
                popup='QuadClass: '+Qclass[row['QuadClass']]).add_to(marker_cluster)
marker.add_to(features[row['QuadClass']])

for row in pd.unique(df1["QuadClass"]):
    features[row].add_to(m)
folium.LayerControl().add_to(m)
m
```

Answer (score 0):

Found out that folium has this plugin which solves the issue with the MarkerCluster: https://github.com/python-visualization/folium/blob/master/folium/plugins/feature_group_sub_group.py